# If statement and post-increment homework: I'm not getting the result I'm expecting - why?

Tags: c#, if-statement, increment

Sorry if this is a dumb beginner question but I'm completely stumped.

```cs
int i = 0;

if (i == 0)
    i++;
    i++;
if (i == 3)
    i += 2;
    i += 2;

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Ok, my logic, so if `i = 0`, add `1`, then add `1` to that. So in the end `i = 2`.

Except it's not, it prints out `4`.

The only way that could happen is if it went trough the second "if statement". Right?

What am I missing?

Comment: Whitespace doesn't set scope in C#. You'll need to use braces to indicate what lines fall under the if condition beyond the first one.

Comment: `if` without braces only executes the single following line.

Comment: Debug, then you will see?

Comment: As mentioned by others, it's because of the scope of your if statements, particularly the second one.

Comment: Yes! I added the braces and got the expected result! 
Thank you all very much!

Comment: It is recommended to always use braces, even for single statement, to avoid this kind of confusion. [More info and samples in the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets { } for anything more than a one line conditional
or only the first line of code after it will get executed when the conditional is true.

```
/*
for example would be 

if (i == 0) 
{
    i++; 
    i++; 
}
*/

int i = 0;

//this is true
if (i == 0)
    i++; // so only this line gets executed i = 1
    i++; // this will get executed no matter what. i = 2
//at this point i = 2 so the conditional is false
if (i == 3)
    i += 2; // this line doesn't get executed
    i += 2; /* this is not in curly brackets { } so it will get executed no matter what the conditional returns as .. so i = 4*/

//i = 4
Console.WriteLine(i);
//and that's what prints
```

check this out
https://www.learncs.org/en/Conditionals

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! 
Turns out it was a "tricky" assignment, I didn't notice the lack of braces...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's `4`, let's *format* the code (put right *indents*) and see:

```
int i = 0;   // i == 0

if (i == 0)  // i == 0
    i++;     // i == 1

i++;         // i == 2

if (i == 3)  // i == 2
    i += 2;  // doesn't enter (since i != 3)

i += 2;      // i == 4
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! 
Of course it was the braces!